# Mongodb aggregation framework: list of most popular tags per day

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

This is my db:

```
db.test.insert({"title": "post01", "body" : "something01", "day" : "2010/01/12", "tags" : ["nosql", "winter"]})
db.test.insert({"title": "post02", "body" : "something02", "day" : "2010/01/12", "tags" : ["sledding", "winter"]})
db.test.insert({"title": "post03", "body" : "something03", "day" : "2010/01/12", "tags" : ["winter"]})
db.test.insert({"title": "post04", "body" : "something04", "day" : "2010/01/12", "tags" : ["winter"]})
db.test.insert({"title": "post05", "body" : "something05", "day" : "2010/01/12", "tags" : ["nosql", "sledding"]})
db.test.insert({"title": "post06", "body" : "something06", "day" : "2010/01/12", "tags" : ["winter"]})
db.test.insert({"title": "post07", "body" : "something07", "day" : "2010/01/12", "tags" : ["winter"]})
db.test.insert({"title": "post08", "body" : "something08", "day" : "2010/01/12", "tags" : ["nosql", "winter"]})
db.test.insert({"title": "post09", "body" : "something09", "day" : "2010/01/12", "tags" : ["winter"]})
db.test.insert({"title": "post10", "body" : "something10", "day" : "2010/01/12", "tags" : ["winter"]})
db.test.insert({"title": "post11", "body" : "something11", "day" : "2010/01/12", "tags" : ["nosql", "winter"]})
db.test.insert({"title": "post12", "body" : "something12", "day" : "2010/01/13", "tags" : ["soda"]})
db.test.insert({"title": "post13", "body" : "something13", "day" : "2010/01/13", "tags" : ["php"]})
db.test.insert({"title": "post14", "body" : "something14", "day" : "2010/01/13", "tags" : ["soda"]})
db.test.insert({"title": "post15", "body" : "something15", "day" : "2010/01/13", "tags" : ["soda"]})
db.test.insert({"title": "post16", "body" : "something16", "day" : "2010/01/13", "tags" : ["soda", "php"]})
db.test.insert({"title": "post17", "body" : "something17", "day" : "2010/01/13", "tags" : ["soda"]})
db.test.insert({"title": "post18", "body" : "something18", "day" : "2010/01/14", "tags" : ["nosql"]})
db.test.insert({"title": "post19", "body" : "something19", "day" : "2010/01/14", "tags" : ["nosql", "python"]})
db.test.insert({"title": "post20", "body" : "something20", "day" : "2010/01/14", "tags" : ["nosql", "python"]})
db.test.insert({"title": "post21", "body" : "something21", "day" : "2010/01/14", "tags" : ["nosql"]})
db.test.insert({"title": "post22", "body" : "something22", "day" : "2010/01/14", "tags" : ["nosql"]})
db.test.insert({"title": "post23", "body" : "something23", "day" : "2010/01/14", "tags" : ["python", "winter"]})
db.test.insert({"title": "post24", "body" : "something24", "day" : "2010/01/14", "tags" : ["nosql"]})
db.test.insert({"title": "post25", "body" : "something25", "day" : "2010/01/14", "tags" : ["nosql", "python", "winter"]})
db.test.insert({"title": "post26", "body" : "something26", "day" : "2010/01/14", "tags" : ["nosql"]})
db.test.insert({"title": "post27", "body" : "something27", "day" : "2010/01/14", "tags" : ["nosql", "winter"]})
db.test.insert({"title": "post28", "body" : "something28", "day" : "2010/01/14", "tags" : ["nosql"]})
db.test.insert({"title": "post29", "body" : "something29", "day" : "2010/01/14", "tags" : ["nosql"]})
db.test.insert({"title": "post30", "body" : "something30", "day" : "2010/01/14", "tags" : ["python"]})
db.test.insert({"title": "post31", "body" : "something31", "day" : "2010/01/14", "tags" : ["nosql", "winter"]})
db.test.insert({"title": "post32", "body" : "something32", "day" : "2010/01/14", "tags" : ["nosql"]})
db.test.insert({"title": "post33", "body" : "something33", "day" : "2010/01/14", "tags" : ["nosql", "python"]})
db.test.insert({"title": "post34", "body" : "something34", "day" : "2010/01/14", "tags" : ["nosql"]})
```

I would like to get a list of the most popular tags of the last N days, something like:

```
{ "day" : "2010/01/14", "tags" : { "python" : 6, "winter" : 4, "nosql" : 15 ] }
{ "day" : "2010/01/13", "tags" : { "soda" : 5, "php" : 2 } }
```

I've been able only to achieve:

```
{ "tags" : [ "python", "winter", "nosql" ], "counts" : [ 6, 4, 15 ], "day" : "2010/01/14" }
{ "tags" : [ "soda", "php" ], "counts" : [ 5, 2 ], "day" : "2010/01/13" }
```

with:

```
db.test.aggregate({"$unwind" : "$tags"}, {"$group" : {"_id" : {"day" : "$day", "tags" : "$tags"}, "count" : {"$sum" : 1}}}, {"$group" : {"_id" : "$_id.day", "tags" : {"$push" : "$_id.tags"}, "counts" : {"$push" : "$count"}}}, {"$project" : {"day" : "$_id", "_id" : 0, "tags" : 1, "counts" : 1}}, {"$sort" : {"day" : -1}}, {"$limit" : 2})
```

It seems I need something like "$addToSubdocument" : {"subdocument" : {"$key" : "$value"}} to be able to push my tags and their values inside my "tags" subdocument, or maybe I simply miss something trivial?

Comment: If you are looking exact format, do it on client side or use map-reduce on mongodb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MongoDB aggregation framework, you can't use values as keys. It appears from your desired output, you are intending to do so.

However, with help of aggregation framework and client side logic, you can transform result into format you want.

e.g. in MongoDB shell, you can run following query. (Or any language with supported MongoDB driver)

```
var items = {};

db.test.aggregate([
   {$match: {day:{$lte: "2010/01/14", $gte: "2010/01/13"}}},
   {$unwind: "$tags"},
   {$group:{_id:{ day: "$day", tag: "$tags"}, count: {$sum:1}}},
   {$project:{_id:0, "tag":"$_id.tag", "day":"$_id.day", count:1}},
   {$sort:{day:1}}
]).forEach(function(d){
  var eItem = items[d.day];
  if(eItem != null)
  {
     eItem.tags[d.tag] = d.count;
  }
  else
  {
    var item = {};
    item.day = d.day;
    item.tags = {};
    item.tags[d.tag] = d.count;
    items[d.day]=item;
  }
});

printjson(items);
```

Output will be:

```
{ 
    "2010/01/13" : {
        "day" : "2010/01/13", 
        "tags" : {
            "soda" : 5, 
            "php" : 2
        }
    }, 
    "2010/01/14" : {
        "day" : "2010/01/14", 
        "tags" : {
            "nosql" : 15, 
            "winter" : 4, 
            "python" : 6
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Saleem. My main concern is exploring the limits of the aggregation framework, so if I need to add client side logic it's the end of the road for me. I forget to match the day tag at the beginning to cut down the results instead of limiting at the end of the pipeline, but that was an oversight fortunately.
Do you think upstream is willing to discuss implementing such a feature or they already expressed their concerns against it?

Comment: It's good idea and you can file a feature request at jira.mongodb.com.

Comment: You should explorer map-reduce as they run on server side and perform much better than processing on client side.